# SharpDevelop or Express editions

Tags: c#, .net, ide, sharpdevelop

Since there is a Sharpdevelop 3.0 ( http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/ ) can anybody tell me how it compares to the Express Editions ? ( http://www.microsoft.com/Express/ )

I tried to find differences, but could only find this old post http://community.icsharpcode.net/blogs/mattward/pages/VisualStudioExpressComparison.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think SharpDevelop doesn't have intellisense. I can't stress how important intellisense is while developing!

Comment: SharpDevelop does have intellisense.

Answer (score 20):

I wrote a blog-post about it, you can find it [here](http://blog.softwarefun.nl/?p=10)

In my conclusion I say:

Conlusion
If I have to choose for web applications than the express edition wins easily. The build in webserver, the graphical designer with split screen functionality and javascript debugging just make it too good.
If you think you really need to work with a database from within the IDE than also SharpDevelop is not for you. If you want to create a windows forms or console application both will work fine, if you want to build these applications more seriously and use a source control system, static code analysis and stylecop from the IDE you need SharpDevelop !

If the express editions would allow third party extensibility (Resharper) and solve my little annoyances,  it would be number one.
If SharpDevelop would get a resharper add-in, a graphical designer for web pages and a build in web server, it would be number one.

Answer (score 8):

SharpDevelop is a free/opensource project. Where as Microsoft Visual Studio Express Edition is a crippled Visual Studio lacking some of the tool/features that help in release commercial software.

If you are planing on using Visual Studio in the future, then use express edition. Otherwise I would highly recommend SharpDevelop.

In terms of features, they both have debuggers, they both have syntax highlighting and code completion. They both will have all the features you expect from a full out RAD IDE for .Net.

Answer (score 0):

The other issue that is worth mentioning is the unit testing support in Sharpdevelop. Nunit can be integrated into the IDE and that is a huge gain IMO. Unit testing in #Develop is far superior to MSTest and Nunit with VS is not integrated into the IDE.